# VMware Workstation: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm stuck with this message in VMware Workstation 15.5.2 and unable to turn on the VM. Deleting `.lck` files that many people suggest doesn't help.

Here is the full error message:

```
The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.

Cannot open the disk 'G:/Windows XP Professional (5)-1.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.

Module 'Disk' power on failed.

Failed to start the virtual machine.
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

if you are this .lok file issue please copy this code and past in notepad and save the file in your vm machine directory as name is removed.bat extension and then go this directory and run this removed.bat file and start the .lok file again ,.and now your problem is resolve Thanks.